# Grails war deployement on WSAS

Tags: grails, websphere, war

I generate a war using grails war, but when I deploy it to Websphere I have errors, what features I need to add so I can run my war under WSAS, here are the errors → http://paste.ubuntu.com/6179593/

*Note: The web page show me this error → Context Root Not Found*

Answer (score 0):

According log there is no problem and application has started successfully.

Check your [Virtual Hosts](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/ccws_vhost.html&resultof=%22Virtual%22%20%22virtual%22%20%22Hosts%22%20%22host%22%20) settings.

There is good [article](http://www.christianoestreich.com/2012/10/deloying-grails-2-to-websphere/) about grails application deployment.